# Numerical prediction using Machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, classification

I got started with naive numerical prediction. Here is the training data

https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/75d6d5f9c4fbaaaaffe8258073d00a75

Test data

https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/0f93ecf5fe8ec5fccc8a7f360a6c3950

I wrote basic scikit learn code to train and test.

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression, BayesianRidge, OrthogonalMatchingPursuitCV, SGDRegressor
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

class NumericPrediction(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dataPrediction(self):
        Train = pd.read_csv("data_scientist_assignment.tsv", sep='\t', parse_dates=['date'])
        Train_visualize = Train
        Train['timestamp'] = Train.date.values.astype(pd.np.int64)
        Train_visualize['date'] = Train['timestamp']
        print Train.describe()
        x1=["timestamp", "hr_of_day"]
        test=pd.read_csv("test.tsv", sep='\t', parse_dates=['date'])
        test['timestamp'] = test.date.values.astype(pd.np.int64)
        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
        # print(model)
        # print model.score(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
        print model.predict(test[x1])

        Train.hist()
        pl.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NumericPrediction().dataPrediction()
```

But accuracy is very low here. Because approach is very naive. Any better suggestion to improve accuracy ( In terms of algorithm, example, reference, library)?

Answer (score 3):

For starter, your 'test' set doesn't look right. Please check it.

Secondly, your model is doomed to fail. Plot your data - what do you see? Clearly we have a seasonality here, while linear regression assumes that observations are independent. It's important to observe that you are dealing here with *time series*.

R language is excellent when it comes to time series, with advanced packages for time series forecasting like *bsts*. Still, Python here will be just as good. *Pandas* module is going to serve you well. Mind that you might not necessarily have to use machine learning here. Check *ARMA* and *ARIMA*. [Bayesian structural time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_structural_time_series) are also excellent.

[Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/) is a very good article that guides you through basics of dealing with time series data.